“No Text Editor Active” Warning When Running Jupyter Notebook in VS Code Using R Kernel
When I was using Jupyter Notebook in VS Code to run R code, there is always a warning popping out, which says "no text editor active. Source: R". I do not know what it means, but everything seems to work fine for me. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this warning? 
Also, FYI, this warning does not pop up when I write R script. It only shows up when I was using Jupyter Notebook.
I tried to re-install the R extension in VS Code. But it still shows up frequently.

I see the same thing, but no idea how to get rid of it.

This also started recently for me

Have you solved this problem?

Facing this issue, would appreciate if someone else finds a solution!

On the status bar (the bar at the bottom of the screen), there should be a cell that says "R: (not attached)." If you click on this, it will attach an R terminal to the notebook, and the warning should not pop up anymore.

This caused that section of the status bar to be replaced with R: (my R version number), but it did not stop the No text editor active. popups for me.

Disable R extension and restart VS Code. The warning will disappear.
If you just run R code in Jupyter notebooks within VS Code, the R extension for VS Code (reditorsupport.r) is not strictly necessary. However, it does provide additional features and conveniences, specifically for working with R scripts and R Markdown files directly in VS Code.

This worked for me.
